# How can I read a utf-8 value in my servlet

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets, utf-8

In my servlet I save to a String variable, a value which I get form a form (with POST) in my JSP page.This value sometimes isn't in English..

```
s1 = request.getParameter("Country");
```

Then to test, what I just read I print it to the log screen and I got `$%^&` when it isn't in English. I tried to add

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

in my jsp page and I also checked if there is this in the `server.xml`

```
URIEncoding="utf-8"
```

But It did't change anything.. What can i do?

**EDIT**
I added to my servlet the following

```
if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        }
```

inside the `protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {`

but i still have the problem

Comment: Is it a GET or a POST parameter?

Comment: see this excellend post by @balusc http://balusc.blogspot.jp/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: @BalusC I read your answer but nothing happened.... (I update the question of what i did)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using tomcat, you can try their utf8 encoding filter (add it to your web.xml of course). Their filter is called org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter, or if you don't want to depend on 3rd party then you can peek at their source code and write your own, it's not very complicated.

See also
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding